# How to fire an event immediately a JTable JScrollpane is activated

Tags: java

Just as the title suggests, I built a Java application that displays the results of students. Everything is working fine, however I was only able to display a set number of rows at a time applying some conditions, by using the setMxRows() method of the PreparedStatement object. 
. However, I wish to load all the results sequentially and anytime the Jscrollpane is visible, meaning the results have overflown the available space on the JTable, I would get the id of the last row that activated the Jscrollpane and then reload the results where id is less than this particular id. Please how do I achieve this or is there a better way to get around this. I appreciate your answers in advance

Comment: You can use the `JScrollBar`s themselves and add an `AdjustmentListener` to them, this will tell you when they have "scrolled". The problem you're really going to face is having the need to know that there are actually more rows available, and padding the `JTable` with "empty" data to allow the `JScrollPane` to display the scroll bars.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me see if I can work around your suggestion.